# Is there any way of keeping a AndroidKeyStoreEntry even if the App is uninstalled?

Tags: java, android, security, encryption, android-keystore

Is there any way of keeping a KeyStoreEntry of an App even if the App is uninstalled?

We are generating a RSA-KeyPair for a secure device identification, which is stored on the KeyStore. The PublicKey is stored on the backend.

```
 val generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
        if (isSDKVersionEqualOrHigherThan23()) {
            generator.initialize(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                "keystoreAlias",
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                .build())
        }
```

If the user is now uninstalling and then reinstalling the app, the RSA-KeyPair changes, and the PublicKey check on the backend fails.

Is there a way to either keep the KeyStore entry on uninstall OR make sure that the same KeyPair is generated again on the same device (e.g. by adding a parameter?)

Comment: Using external storage?

Comment: Can you briefly explain what you mean by that?

Comment: I can't be sure from what I've read, but I think the answer is no.

Comment: @Ziiiimon there are two types of storage in Android: internal and external. Internal storage is the apps data, which **gets deleted when it is uninstalled**. External storage is public, but the data made by a single app isn't deleted when the app is. So if you use external storage, if that is a possibility, the keystore will not be deleted when the app is. I have no clue if you **can** save it to external storage though.  And external storage is the public storage, not just an SD card

Comment: I think that is not an option, because it would leave the private key unprotected on the device.